# Preserving alpha values in BufferedImage.setRGB()?

Tags: java

I'd like to composite a few images together. Each image has some transparency to it. I'm trying to use BufferedImage for this but there doesn't seem to be any way to use it for this purpose?

We only get the BufferedImage.setRGB() method. Instead I need something where transparent pixels won't overwrite the pixel values below them. How can I go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* imageType should be one of the variants that includes alpha  */
final BufferedImage composited = new BufferedImage(width, height, imageType);
final Graphics graphics = composited.getGraphics();
for (final Image layer : layers) {
  /* draw the image at 0,0 */
  graphics.drawImage(layer, 0, 0, null);
}
graphics.dispose();
```

Comment: Ok, just took a look at WritableRaster, I see it has a setPixels() method, but will that just do a straight overwrite of the destination raster (like BufferedImage is doing right now), or does it respect the alpha channel inherently? Or is there some other method in there that I'm missing and should be using? Thanks!

Comment: @user291701 `setPixels` expects an array where each element is a sample; for ARGB, it would take four elements per pixel, since each channel requires a sample.

Comment: Ok but it's not blending the pixels, it's doing a straight overwrite. I don't see something in WritableRaster that lets us do an additive composition - we're just directly resetting each pixel value?

Comment: @user291701 if you want composition, create a `BufferedImage` with the desired color/sample model and acquire its graphics context. Layer your images on to it via `drawImage`.